# Should the How to Ask page be fleshed out a tad?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Compare our [How to Ask page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) with [that of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I refer to the latter almost daily to assist and prod folks who post lazy questions lacking in critical detail. I'd like to do the same here, but our version doesn't contain much information or links to other resources. Examples would be very helpful, too.

Is this a good idea? How can we make it happen?

Comment: I'm with you 100% on this one! Having a section on "provide clear, focused pictures that show the problem area", and maybe even some specifics on how to take pictures of wiring issues (both sides of all devices involved, include pics showing the wiring into the back of the box, etc.) would make life _much_ easier!

Answer (score 3):

Mods don't have the ability to update that page, but we can edit [on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) with custom content.

The [how to ask](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page appears to be the same for [all](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) [the](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) [SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) [sites](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) [that](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) [I](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) [looked](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) [at](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (with the exception of [server fault](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)) so I assume this requires SE themselves to edit. If there's something you'd like to see changed with the on-topic page, feel free to raise the meta request with specifics for what you'd like to see done.

Comment: I'd like to revisit this. It's an ongoing hassle to not have a good example of a quality question at hand. Is there any way to contact SE and find out what's necessary? I'm willing to do the work to develop the page, but the on-topic suggestion doesn't really meet my goals.

Comment: @isherwood Here's details on how to get SE's community managers involved: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377058/what-site-specific-changes-can-be-made-to-the-ask-question-page-to-help-askers-o